Table Borders in an Outlook email with HTML
I have a macro that generates an Outlook email.  One of the requirements is to add table to the email.  The other requirement is to have the 1st part of the email in French and then the 2nd part of the email in English.  So I'm replicating the table with different headings.  I've got it working except that the table borders are different and I would like to make them consistent.
I'm self taught from what I can learn from sites like this but I cannot figure out how to make the borders the same on both tables..  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance....
Here is the code I'm using:
TmpStr = ""
TmpStr = Trim(Workbooks(DataBook).Worksheets(1).Cells(r, 6))
            
strBeforeRows1 = ""
strRows1 = ""
             
strBeforeRows1 = "<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse:" & _
"collapse;}</style></head><body>" & _
"<table style=""width:60%""><tr>" & _
"<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Field 1</th>" & _
"<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Field 2</th>" & _
"<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Field 3</th>" & _
"<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Field 4</th>" & _
"<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Field 5</th>" & _
"<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Field 6</th>"
                
Do While Trim(Workbooks(DataBook).Worksheets(1).Cells(r, 6)) = TmpStr
            
     DoEvents
                
//     Execute code to fill variables for the tables
  
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<tr>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<td ""col width=15%"" ""col align=center"">" & MyVIN & "</td>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=left"">" & MyPlate & "</td>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & MyYear & "</td>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & MyMake & "</td>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & MyModel & "</td>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & MySeries & "</td>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "</tr>"
                
r = r + 1
                
Loop
            
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<tr>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<td ""col width=15%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows1 = strRows1 & "</tr>"
            
strAfterRows1 = "</table></body>"
    
StrAll1 = strBeforeRows1 & strRows1 & strAfterRows1
            
StrBody = ""
StrBody2 = ""
StrBody3 = ""
StrBody4 = ""
StrBody5 = ""
StrBody6 = ""
StrBody7 = ""
   
//    Execute code to fill more variables            

StrBody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & "verbiage"
            
StrBody2 = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" &  "signature
            
StrBody3 = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & StrBody & StrAll1 & StrBody2 
             
StrBody4 = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" &  "English verbiage"

strBeforeRows2 = ""
strBeforeRows2 = "<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse:" & _
"collapse;}</style></head><body>" & _
"<table style=""width:60%""><tr>" & _
"<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Field 1</th>" & _
"<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Field 2</th>" & _
"<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Field 3</th>" & _
"<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Field 4</th>" & _
"<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Field 5</th>" & _
"<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Field 6</th>"
            
strRows2 = strRows2 & "<td ""col width=15%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows2 = strRows2 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows2 = strRows2 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows2 = strRows2 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows2 = strRows2 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows2 = strRows2 & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows2 = strRows2 & "</tr>"

strAfterRows2 = "</table></body>"
            
StrAll2 = ""
StrAll2 = strBeforeRows2 & strRows1 & strAfterRows1

StrBody5 = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _ "english signature"
                
StrBody6 = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & StrBody4 & StrAll2 & StrBody5 
                
StrBody7 = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & StrBody3 & StrBody6

// code to generate email

You have two opening <head> and <body> tags - they should only show up once...   Also repeating (and not closing) some of your <font>  tags

Also - table column width % should add to 100% if all columns have a specified width.

You can restructure your code and clean up the HTML so it's valid (only one head and body element for example).
Try something like this (untested):
Sub Tester()

    Dim html As String, tblBody As String, arrWidths, ws As Worksheet, DataBook
    Dim r As Long, TmpStr As String
    Dim MyVIN, MyPlate, MyYear, MyMake, MyModel, MySeries
    
    '...
    '...
    
    Set ws = Workbooks(DataBook).Worksheets(1)
    
    TmpStr = Trim(ws.Cells(r, 6)).Value
                
    html = "<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid gray;" & _
             "border-collapse:collapse;}</style></head><body>"
    
    arrWidths = Array(15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10) 'array of table column widths
    
    'get table body (used in both tables)
    tblBody = ""
    Do While Trim(Workbooks(DataBook).Worksheets(1).Cells(r, 6)) = TmpStr
         'populate variables and add table row
         tblBody = tblBody & ContentRow(Array(MyVIN, MyPlate, MyYear, MyMake, MyModel, MySeries), arrWidths)
         r = r + 1
    Loop
    
    html = html & "<h2>Some opening text here</h2>"
    
    html = html & "<table style=""width:60%"">" 'open the table
    'first table headers
    html = html & HeaderRow("Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3", "Field 4", "Field 5", "Field 6")
    html = html & tblBody            'add the body
    html = html & vbLf & "</table>"  'close the table
    
    html = html & "<h2>Second header text</h2>"
    
    html = html & "<table style=""width:60%"">" 'open second table
    'second table headers
    html = html & HeaderRow("Other 1", "Other 2", "Other 3", "Other 4", "Other 5", "Other 6")
    html = html & tblBody            'add the body
    html = html & vbLf & "</table>"  'close the table
    
    html = html & "</body>" 'close the body
    
    'use the html...
    
End Sub

'Push out all that additional concatenation into a couple of functions...

'Return HTML for a table header row where header texts are
'  passed to `headers()`
Function HeaderRow(ParamArray headers()) As String
    Dim rv As String, el
    rv = "<tr>"
    For Each el In headers
        rv = rv & vbLf & "   <th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">" & el & "</th>"
    Next el
    HeaderRow = rv & vbLf & "</tr>"
End Function

'Return HTML for a table content row where content values are
'  passed to `values`, and % column widths to `widths`
Function ContentRow(values, widths) As String
    Dim rv As String, i As Long
    rv = "<tr>"
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        rv = rv & vbLf & "   <td ""col width=" & widths(i) & _
                 "%"" ""col align=center"">" & values(i) & "</td>"
    Next i
    ContentRow = rv & vbLf & "</tr>"
End Function


...........Thanks for the suggestions.  I'm adding 2 tables to the email; which is why I thought I needed a  and  tag for each table.  thanks
